# ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

In my game, I encapsulate my addChild so that I can have an array of all the objects that are on stage for later garbage collection. this is how I do so

```
public function addGameChild(object:gameObject,isDisplay:Boolean = true):void
        {
            if(isDisplay)
                addChild(object);

            gameStage.push(object);
        }
```

It adds it just fine. Later, I check to see if its ready for garbage. this

```
private function loop(e:Event):void {

            for(var t = 0; t < gameStage.length; t++)
            {               
                gameStage[t].updateObject();
            }

            for(var g = 0; g < gameStage.length; g++)
            {               
                if(gameStage[g].garbage)
                {
                    removeChild(gameStage[g]);
                }
            }
        }
```

each gameObject has a property called garbage that is a boolean that is set when ready to be removed. When I set it to tree, this is what happens

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
```

anyone have any clue on whats happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out. I forgot to splice(g,1) the object after removing it. It looped again and tried to remove the object again and thats when the error was thrown

Comment: what do you mean with splice?